# Point client to the right server base on there URL (web)

Tags: azure, nginx, iis, routes, subdomain

I have 2 production azure virtual IIS machines (Windows server 2016), one on Europe and the other on US,
every customer gets his own isolated sit on the server Europe or us, based on his location.

**Example of how it works now:**
lets say if customer is from US, his app is only on US server, so:
1)  I'm pointing him with Goddady DNS "a" record to the right server ("customerName.example.com" --- > "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx") 
2) I'm using URL rewrite on the IIS ROOT level https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}.
**This picture demonstrate  how it works now.**
[image: what i have now]

**my goals are:**
1) use `*` on GoDaddy as an "a" record that pointing one service/server/sass (traffic manager/controller/something else) so i will never need to add records to for each customer (its impossible to add more than one "*" per domain name)
2) do it better than what i have now.

**This picture demonstrate what im trying to accomplish. **
[image: this is what I'm trying to do]

so, please help me: 
- what I'm trying to accomplish is good practice? 
- is there an "azure way" to implement what i want? 
- nginx is good idea?
- what are my options?

tnx.

Comment: Why are there multiple sites in each region?

Comment: I suggest you could consider using Azure traffic manager to achieve your requirement. The traffic manager contains the Geographic traffic-routing method so that users are directed to specific endpoints (Azure, External or Nested) based on which geographic location their DNS query originates from.  Detials, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#geographic-traffic-routing-method)